# How to fix "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Tags: discord.js

I am setting up a `discord.js` bot and trying to add a help command.

I have tried putting `const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();` in the help command file but got an error.

```
const { prefix } = require('../token.json');
    execute(message, args) {
    const data = [];
const { commands } = message.client;

if (!args.length) {
  const name = args[0].toLowerCase();
const command = commands.get(name) || commands.find(c => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name));
```

I expected it to show a help command and what each command is about when you do ?

Comment: it would be useful to include detailed error messages you've seen, otherwise we have to guess what "in the help command file but got an error." could mean. Keep at it.

Answer (score 2):

`args[0]` is undefined. If `!args.length` returns true, it means that `args.length` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. Therefore, an element in `args` *can't* exist.